# Referencing a css :before selector with Capybara

Tags: css, rspec, capybara

I don't know if this can be done, but I would like to test in Rspec with Capybara to verify that a particular css class exists. This is in my css:

```
.thing-before::before, .my-class{
<content to create a bullet point>
}
```

I have an element with class `.my-class`, and before this, the css creates a bullet point. I want to use Capybara to verify the presence of `.thing-before`. Since Capybara tests the html page, and the `.thing-before` is not in the html page, I wouldn't be surprised if Capybara can't do this. I appreciate any help.

Comment: This is probably not the right kind of thing to test with your specs... it screams of making your tests way too brittle to minor styling things. Check styling by actually going to look at your site and making sure it looks right.

Comment: Thank you Taryn East, you're right. I have checked it manually, but I was curious whether there was a way to do this. I agree, its too brittle.